# Retention policy on library is not running

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention, information-policy

Within one library in SharePoint Online I have added a retention stage after changing the source to library and folder.

I am trying to move/copy a document to another location if it is 20 days old.

Accordingly I have set the Time Period to `created + 20 days`. As action I have selected `Transfer to another location` and I have selected the destination location accordingly.

But none of the expired items (`created + 20 days`) are moving to the destination location.

What could cause retention policy not firing?

Answer (score 1):

Item expiration is handled by two timer jobs in the farm, `Information management policy` and `Expiration policy`. The first job runs through and marks all expired items ready for expiration, and the other job comes through and cleans them up. In a default SharePoint installation (on prem), these are run weekly. These can be adjusted to run daily to handle expiration in "real time".

However, in SharePoint Online, we do not have the ability to modify those timer jobs. My inclination is that this is still a default 1 week setting.

Keep an eye on your documents and you will see they will eventually disappear. If you want to know the exact timing, you can open a support case and the technicians should be able to tell you when these timer jobs run on your tenant.